# is there's a head first version of iPhone & iPad development which covers SDK 5.1 or Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i just was asking about the existence of a headfirst book(iPhone&iPad development) which covers SDK 5 or XCODE 4, if there isn't what the best books to study iPhone and iPad development on the latest release of the SDK and XCODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book might be very useful for you. BookDepository: http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-X-Games-Development-Using-IOS-X-SDK-for-iPad-iPhone-iPod-Touch-Lucas-Jordan/9781430237105. If you going to buy it there is a 38% of discount.

Comment: sorry, i'm not going to develop games for iOS, i'm just new to iOS and want a book like headfirst to put me on the road, but unfortunately the version which i found is not updated to the latest release of the SDK AND Xcode, so i hope to find a version which is updated to the latest SDK and Xcode

Comment: Oops! Sorry, look on this: http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/iPhone-iPad-Apps-for-Absolute-Beginners-IOS-5-Edition-Rory-Lewis/9781430236023. As well with discount.

Comment: That's all what I found. The others are wasn't updated yet to iOS 5 or they are on iOS Game Development.

Comment: @Eslam I mean you can get this book: http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Head-First-iPhone-iPad-Development-Dan-Pilone/9781449387822. All of theirs books are awesome for newbie, but I strongly recommend you to look on the book that I gave you in the previous comment.

Comment: @Eslam But obviuosly if you like this series of books you can purchase it. Again it is with 33% of discount. I'm always using this website to purchase the books. Fast delivery and really low prices. But if you want you can find it at Amazon or Ebay. It is depends on where you live.

Answer (score 1):

On the Head First blog, they say that a [Head First iPhone and iPad for iOS 5 will be out in early 2012](http://blogs.oreilly.com/headfirst/2011/10/using-head-first-iphone-and-ip.html#more).

If you can't wait, [Beginning iOS 5 Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430236054) supports the new iOS, although their Xcode version is 4.2, while the latest is 4.3. It's always been a very thorough book.

The 3rd edition of [The Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521) is out in a few weeks, and it supports iOS 5 and Xcode 4.3.